# Images provided by HTTP providers are not loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, http, https, mixed-content

I am working on an Open Source decentralised search engine [susper.com](https://susper.com) . We fetch the results from P2P search engine [YaCy](https://yacy.net/) .The front end of Susper is built using Angular. Currently we have implemented an image section which fetches results from YaCy but we are unable to see results from http providers in Image section. The image results from http providers are shown as broken image.[image] Can anyone suggest any way of allowing http providers to show results.

Answer (score 1):

I've go to your site, sorry for leaving wrong comment (deleted), if you try to inspect the image and visit it directly by link, you'll found out it's actually the original sources' HTTPS certification issue (see screenshot below). You can add exception for your own side to see the image (I assume, haven't tried since it might be an actual security issue), but your visitor will need to add exception them self too, so it's not actually a solution. I'll suggest just ignore or filter out the specific domain, unless you have the permission to modify the server-side configuration of the domain.

[image]

Also, every image that's not showing have its own issue, some is 503 error, some is can't establish connection, some is SSL error. Above is the first error I spot, I suggest you copy the image location by right click and view each errors by yourself.